# Print triangle with width and height parameters

Tags: java, loops

I am quite new to programming and Java. I need to print an asteriks and dot triangle with respect to width and height parameters.

So far, I can print only asteriks triangle with an only one parameter (height).  (Assume 6 is given as parameter to the function)

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
    {
       for(int j=6; j>=i; j--)
       {
          System.out.print(".");
       }
       for(int x=0; x<=(2*i); x++)
       {
          System.out.print("*");
       }
       for(int k=6; k>=i; k--)
       {
          System.out.print(".");
       }
     System.out.print("\n");
    }
 }
```

I want to give two parameters(width and height) to the function. However, I cannot manage adding a second parameter.

The expected output is (with width -11- and height -8- parameters):

```
triangle 11 8

.....*.....
....**.....
...****....
...*****...
..******...
.********..
.*********.
***********
```

However, I got the following output (with one parameter which only height -6-):

```
triangle 6

.......*.......
......***......
.....*****.....
....*******....
...*********...
..***********..
```

Could you please help me? How can I add a second parameter to my function and fix my problem?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I would say that in you first example width is 11 and height is 8. Am I right?

Comment: yes, you're right. the question is edited.

Comment: How could we model the desired outcome with pseudocode? We need a program that draws one asterisk on the top level, plus two on each subsequent level. It should draw a period everywhere else.

Comment: You should note that there are height and width parameters. That means we cannot add two asteriks at each level. If so, one parameter would be enough. But it is not. Let me explain triangle 11 8 example output: It starts with 1 asteriks at the top but see there are 2 asteriks at second line, 4 asteriks at third line and so on. The key point here is that there must be 11 asteriks and totally 8 rows at the end in a triangle shape. It does not matter how many asteriks you increment. You should just maintain the triangle shape while incrementing asteriks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing several things which do not match your example.

First, you aren't using the arguments at all. You said to assume 6 is passed to your main method as an argument, but all I see is hardcoded 6's in your code. You should be calling args[0] and args[1] to use the two arguments.

Second, your loop logic is off if you want to get the result given with the arguments provided in the example. Your outer loop is fine for the number of lines, but your inner loops don't build the individual lines exactly right. The tricky part here is that the contents of each line need to consider the ratio of the width to the height.

Here is an example which should fix both issues:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int width = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   int height = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

   for(int i=0; i<height; i++) {
       int starsThisLine = (int) Math.round(width * ((i+1) / (double) height));
       int dotsBeforeStars = (int) Math.round((width - starsThisLine) / 2.0);

       for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
       {
          if (j < dotsBeforeStars)
             System.out.print(".");
          } else if  (j < dotsBeforeStars + starsThisLine) {
             System.out.print("*");
          } else {
             System.out.print(".");
          }
       }
     System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Note that this may not print the result exactly, but should look close enough. If you need it to be exact, you may need to tune the ratios a bit.

Comment: Dont just paste your thoughts as answer, you have to be sure of what you are saying.. I have run this code and it is not even near the solution

Comment: @ZainArshad - Good call. I've updated it. To be fair to me though, saying it wasn't even near the solution is inaccurate. It was correct if taken more as pseudocode. The issue was compilation and conversion errors, so a better characterization is that it is close, but just needs some cleanup to work correctly. That being said, you are right that I should have taken more time to make sure it worked before posting.

Comment: Please upvote/accept this answer if it now correctly solves the problem.